# How do i insert a certain string in another string at a particular location in r?

Tags: r, text-mining

I am new to R. It may be a very simple thing to do but I am not able figure it out.

Say, I have a string as follows:

```
This is an example string.
```

Now I want to make it as follows:

```
This is an (example/sample) string.
```

I know the location at which the change is to be made. (12th character in the given string).

I have a lot of strings where i need to perform similar operation.

Comment: Are you always replacing "example" with "(example/sample)"? Do you at least always know not only the start position, but also the length of the word? Do you know the full replacement value or do you just know what word you are adding so you need to extract the other word from the text? Please clarify exactly what you need to do.

Answer (score 3):

I think I don't understand the problem but if I do you could use `gsub` here:

```
x <- "This is an example string."

gsub("example", "(example/sample)", x)

## [1] "This is an (example/sample) string."
```

Comment: My thoughts too, by my guess is that the word beginning at the particular position is initially unknown... maybe...

Comment: @jbaums sure but this is probably the most direct solution to the problem posed by the OP. It's up to them to make it clear what they want.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution with regular expressions:

```
# the string
s <- "This is an example string."
# the position of the target's first character 
pos <- 12

# create a regular expression
reg <- paste0("^(.{", pos - 1, "})(.+?\\b)(.*)")
# [1] "^(.{11})(.+?\\b)(.*)"

# modify string
sub(reg, "\\1\\(\\2/sample\\)\\3", s)
# [1] "This is an (example/sample) string."
```

Comment: You don't really need to match the end of the string, only to replace it with itself. This would suffice as far as I can tell: `sub(paste0("^(.{", pos - 1, "})(.+?\\b)"), "\\1\\(\\2/sample\\)", s)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another regex flavoured solution using a lookbehind:

```
s <- "This is an example string."
pos <- 12
replacement <- '(example/sample)'
sub(sprintf('(?<=^.{%s})\\S*\\b', pos-1), replacement, s, perl=TRUE)

## [1] "This is an (example/sample) string."
```

Lookbehind `(?<=x)` is useful because regex within it is part of the pattern but doesn't become part of the match (so we don't have to capture them and replace them later). The pattern above says: "The beginning of the string, followed by 11 characters, preceding zero or more non-whitespace characters, followed by a word boundary. Only the non-whitespace characters are replaced, by `replacement`.

**Update**

An alternative is to use `strsplit` to create a vector of words, and then identify the position in the vector of the character of interest (e.g. the 12th character), subsequently replacing that element with your new word. This is a bit slower than the regex approach, but makes it straightforward to request multiple replacements (at multiple character positions). For example:

```
f <- function(string, pos, new) {
  s <- strsplit(string, '\\s')[[1]]
  i <- findInterval(pos, c(gregexpr('(?<=\\b)\\w', string, perl=TRUE)[[1]], 
                           nchar(string)))
  s[i] <- mapply(sub, s[i], patt='\\b[[:alnum:]-]+\\b', repl=new, perl=TRUE)
  paste0(s, collapse=' ')
}

f('This is an example string.', c(12, 20), c('excellent', 'function'))

## [1] "This is an excellent function."
```

Note that this hyphenated words are fully replaced (i.e. not just the part up to a hyphen) by the replacement, and all other punctuation (outside boundaries of hyphenated words) is retained.

Comment: what if I have to replace two words in a single go? "example" with "example/sample" and "string" with "(string/sentence)". and the final sentence should be "This is an (example/sample) (string/sentence)." In this case the position of the second work would change after modifying the first.